# WSGI : If there aren't any cookies set yet.. *** cookie.load(environ['HTTP_COOKIE']) *** causes the whole script to break

Tags: python, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, wsgi

Apache error_log:

```
cookie.load(environ['HTTP_COOKIE'])
KeyError: 'HTTP_COOKIE'
```

WSGI Script :

```
import Cookie
cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie()

def application(environ, start_response):
    cookie.load(environ['HTTP_COOKIE'])


    a = 'test=2222; path=/; domain=.domain.tld; HttpOnly;'

    x = [('Set-Cookie', a),('Content-Type', 'text/html')]

    start_response('200 OK', x)

    yield 'test'
```

the problem is.. when there is not yet a cookie set at all..

```
 cookie.load(environ['HTTP_COOKIE'])
```

does not know what to do and thus it causes the whole script to break.

Comment: Would like a solution without the "try" and "except" concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if a key exists in the dict:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    if 'HTTP_COOKIE' in environ:
        cookie.load(environ['HTTP_COOKIE'])
```